# How To Change folder permission via SU [root] eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, root

How To Change folder permission via SU [root] eclipse android.

i am making a root application(first time) that change permission of folder.i want to change  permission

```
   /data/data/com.example.app
```

i try this but not working.

```
 final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("su");
                runtime.exec("chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.example.app");

            }

            catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

i grant my app but. dont know why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not heading the right way, try the code below:

```
     suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

     DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

     if (null != os)
     {
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.example.app \n");
        os.flush();
     }
```

Comment: It is copied from other example, I have modified it.